# How can I enforce wrapping the html content for a fixed width using CSS inside Body Tag?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fixed-width

In my HTML document, I want to enforce fixed layout (250px width).

Would you please help me with a CSS snippet that can be used within a body tag so that the html content will be wrapped after a fixed width ?

For example,

```
<body style="width: 250px">
```

This snippet is working in Firefox perfectly, but it is not working in Internet Explorer. Is there any universal technique that will enforce the fixed width for all browsers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work in IE if you have it in Quirks Mode. Make sure you have a `<!DOCTYPE>` and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I did use <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> in my html document and tested in IE 9, but I dont get that fixed layout. Is my <!DOCTYPE not correct ?

Comment: Try `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Hit F12 and check the Document Mode.

Comment: Your doctype triggers quirks mode because you're missing the URI: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` Including the URI will cause it to trigger standards mode. Or, as mentioned, the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` will do just as well, because it doesn't need a URI.

Answer (score 1):

The technique that works on all CSS enabled browsers, even old versions of IE, is to introduce intermediate markup, e.g. `<body><div id="body">...</div></body>`, and set the width on that element, e.g. `#body { width: 250px; }`.

In Quirks Mode, IE treats the `body` element as the root element, hence apparently ignores e.g. the `width` property on it.